# Selecting element by custom data

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html like so:

```
<div mydata style="..." class="..."></div>
```

I want to be able to select all divs that have mydata as an attribute so I can work with them in jquery. I've tried `$('[mydata]')` but that doesn't seam to find anything.
Any thoughts?

Comment: `'[mydata]'` selector should indeed be able to find all elements with that attribute. The problem definitely is elsewhere.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser inspector?

Comment: An example showing that it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqmmWb

Comment: Can't reproduce, which makes this [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's likely this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/497418, but without additional information it's impossible to say.

Comment: Note that inventing your own non-standard HTML attributes (such as `mydata`) will mean your HTML is invalid and could lead to JS and UI problems. You should use `data-*` attributes to add custom data to an element.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMyCrossan, I had naively forgotten about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div[mydata]').each(function() {
// `this` is the div
// $(this)
});
```

or if u set a value to the attribute u can fetch them by

```
$('div[mydata="value"]').each(function() {
// `this` is the div
// $(this)
});
```

**EDIT**

This code snippet finds all of them.

```
 <div adam='l'>geh</div>
 <div adam='j'>asdad</div>
 <div adam='t'>hsad</div>
 <div adam='l'>hessssj</div>
 <div adam='tl'>hej</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[adam]').css({ 'background':'red' });
});
```

Comment: This should work. so probably u have some problem elsewhere

Comment: What if I want it to be on any element with a mydata value, not just a div?

Comment: using just [mydata] works great. I had a load sequence problem. For anyone else with this problem, make sure you stick this in a $(document).ready function or the selector may be called before the elements exist in which case they won't be found.

Comment: a tip. next time, send your code so people can see =) glad i could help ya